Problem reading new definitions from resx files
I have a blazor server project and are using resx files.
It has been working well, but suddenly it doesn't work when adding new definitions to the files.
I have added new definitions in both Resource Explorer and in Legacy. And they are saved as they should.
But when I try to read it from my razor pages, it only finds the old definitions. Not the newly created.
@Resource.mynewdefinition returns error 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'mynewdefinition'
I have cleaned the solution, run new build, restarted application. But nothing helps.
Any suggestions is appreciated.

Go to the Output window in Visual Studio and set the dropdown to Build. Then try rebuilding the project and check if there are any warnings or errors related to the .resx files or the generated .Designer.cs file.

Thanks @liaifat85 but it is only errors about the definitions that are not found in the Output.

Checked Resource.Designer.cs now and it looks like all my newly created definitions is missing there for some reason.

Solution.
If Resource.Designer.cs isn't updating with definitions, right-click on your resx file and select Run Custom Tool.
